# How to say someone's home was something plural?

Tags: grammatical-number

> My true home were the streets of the suburb of XYZ.

Not sure how to say that the streets (plural) were the home of a specific person.

Using the word homeless would be against the intended meaning. This specific person had a family and a house but mostly wandered and slept in  streets or alleyways, because he felt that's where he belonged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My true home was the streets of Chicago. 
Compare that to: The streets of Chicago were my true home.
Both are right.